# How can I retrieve multiple objects with JPA?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, jpa, jpa-2.0

I'm using JPA2/hibernate with this data model:

```
class Stock {
  @ManyToOne
  private StockGroup stockGroup;
  private boolean visible;
}
class StockGroup {
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "stockGroup")
  private List<Stock> stocks;
}
```

I would like to retrieve StockGroup's containing Stock's where `visible==true`.
I've come up with this faulty code:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<StockGroup> q = cb.createQuery(StockGroup.class);
Root<StockGroup> r = q.from(StockGroup.class);
Join<StockGroup, Stock> j = r.join(StockGroup_.stocks, JoinType.INNER);
Predicate p = cb.equal(j.get(Stock_.visible), true);

// This becomes a cartesian product :(
List<StockGroup> l = em.createQuery(q.where(p)).getResultList();   
// Stocks are not filtered on visible :(
l.get(0).getStocks();
```

Is it possible to retrieve the StockGroup and Stock Objects with one CriteriaQuery or can JPA only fill one type at once? Or can i add some Criteria when `.getStocks()` is filled lazily?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The trick to doing this is returning a tuple containing an old-fashioned join between the Stock and the StockGroup, like this:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Tuple> q = cb.createQuery(Tuple.class);
Root<Stock> sRoot = q.from(Stock.class);
Root<StockGroup> sgRoot = q.from(StockGroup.class);

q.select(cb.tuple(sRoot, sgRoot)).where(
    cb.and(cb.equal(sRoot.get(Stock_.stockGroup), sgRoot),
        cb.isTrue(sRoot.get(Stock_.visible))));
List<Tuple> l = em.createQuery(q).getResultList();
```

The tuple is then not fully type safe, but you can reach it by position (or by alias, if you've given your select expressions or roots an alias):

```
for (Tuple t : l) {
    Stock s = (Stock) t.get(0);
    StockGroup sg = (StockGroup) t.get(1);

    System.out.println("Stock is : " + s + "    .... StockGroup: " + sg);
}
```

There's a [good article on IBM DeveloperWorks on JPA2 Typesafe Queries](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-typesafejpa/).

Good luck in your JPA2 endeavors!

Comment: If was afraid of this... manual joins, unsafe casts, vebose syntax and manually putting together objects. Maybe i need to switch to something like OpenJPA or Querydsl.


But still, you answered my question perfectly (I've read the enitre article).


Bonus points to you if you answer the second part: What if I first only retrieve StockGroups, can i add some Criteria when .getStocks() is called? In other words, can I mess with the proxy object?

Comment: I don't think that is supported in JPA -- Where's no such construct (filtered collections), since you'd get an incomplete collection in your object. Nor do I see how OpenJPA would help you, and I don't know enough about QueryDsl to offer advice. Sorry!

Comment: You could, however, add some higher-level methods/helpers to do the manual join, such as manualJoin(cb, sgRoot, sRoot, Stock_.group, cb.isTrue(sRoot.get(Stock_.visible))), and perhaps wrap the tuple list accordingly, as a band-aid of sorts? It's a pity they didn't make Tuple1<T>, Tuple2<T1, T2>, etc.